# ethereum world state size analysis

Tags: go-ethereum, history, mastering-ethereum, storage-trie, disk-space

i am currently researching on the ethereum world state and i need updatad data of space that world state takes up in the storage.
the latest data that i found is https://blog.bitmex.com/bitcoin-vs-ethereum-blockchain-size/ that refrences to @peter_szilagyi on <x.com>
does anyone have newer data?